# arrangements of the nodes on graph network plot

Tags: r, igraph

I'm not a programmer, but for a specific representation of a data set I did a network plot (circle layout) on igraph. I could edit vertex size and colour but I didn't manage to set a specific order of the nodes.

Here's what i did:

g1 <- graph(edges=c("A","B","B","G","G","G","G","B","B","G","G","G","A","G","G","G","A","B","G","G","A","A","B","B","G","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","B","B","H","B","B","G","B","A","A","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","C","C","H","H","F","H","H","H","B","B","B","B","B","C","B","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","B","A","B","B","H","H","G","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","A","A","G","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","C","A","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","G","C","G","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","A","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H"), n=8)

deg1 <- degree(g1, mode="all")

plot(g1, vertex.label.dist=0, vertex.size=deg1,vertex.color=deg1*1,vertex.frame.color="white", layout=layout.circle, main="g1", vertex.label.font=2,vertex.label.cex=2,edge.width=1,
edge.arrow.size=1, edge.curved=0.3)

I would like the nodes on the graph to appear in the following order A, B, C, D, E, F, G and H.

Is it possible? How?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not contain a node named "E", so I just omitted it from the order.

The `permute` function does exactly what you are asking for.

```
g2 = permute(g1, c(1,2,6,7,4,3,5))
deg2 <- degree(g2, mode="all")
plot(g2, vertex.label.dist=0, vertex.size=deg2,vertex.color=deg2*1,
    vertex.frame.color="white", layout=layout.circle, main="g2", 
    vertex.label.font=2,vertex.label.cex=2,edge.width=1, 
    edge.arrow.size=1, edge.curved=0.3)
```

[image: Permuted graph]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I need. I just have one remaining doudbt. How do I know, what number refers to each letter and position on the circle?

Comment: @Eduardo just type `V(g1)$name`